# Select content of text element with tspan specifier in SVG with D3js

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I add a text to an SVG by D3js

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");
var t = svg.append("text");
t.append("tspan").attr("class", "span1").text("This is span 1");
t.append("tspan").attr("class", "span2").text("and this is 2");
```

The SVG element is added and is

`<text>
   <span class="span1">This is span 1</span>
   <span class="span2">and this is 2</span>
</text>`

**How can I retrieve the whole content of the text element with the span specifiers?**

The text is available as

```
var text = t[0][0].textContent;
```

but it does contain "This is span1and this is 2" without the span specifiers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML) in this case:

```
var text = t[0][0].innerHTML;
```